# ansible lineinfile how add multiple lines with multiple dest?

Tags: ansible

I have many lines need to add, like

1. today
2. is
3. a
4. good
5. day

if just one dest, will be

```
- name: add line
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/tmp/aaa.txt"
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "toady"
    - "is"
    - "a"
    - "good"
    - "day"
```

and then, also have many files need to add, like

1. aaa.txt
2. bbb.txt
3. ccc.txt

if just one line, will be

```
- name: add line
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ item }}"
    line: "today"
  with_items:
    - "/tmp/aaa.txt"
    - "/tmp/bbb.txt"
    - "/tmp/ccc.txt"
```

Now I need mix them, both have all dest and all line, but I can't try it success.

Both of them are an array or object, I try many method still fail.

Helppppppp please :(

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nested](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/nested_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-nested-composes-a-list-with-nested-elements-of-other-lists). For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    files: [aaa.txt, bbb.txt, ccc.txt]
    lines: [today, good, day]
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        create: true
        dest: "/tmp/{{ item.0 }}"
        line: "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ files }}"
        - "{{ lines }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/aaa.txt 
today
good
day

shell> cat /tmp/bbb.txt 
today
good
day

shell> cat /tmp/ccc.txt 
today
good
day
```

Comment: I use this method and success! Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! FYI, both solutions are equivalent. See [with_nested and with_cartesian are replaced by loop and the product filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian). It's a matter of personal preference. See the [Note](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops).

Answer (score 3):

Althought this looks a bit weird to me and that I think you should probably consider using `blockinfile` or even better a template, there is a solution to your exact question. One possibility here with the `product` filter:

```yaml
- name: Add several lines to several files
  vars:
    lines:
      - today
      - is
      - a
      - good
      - day
    files:
      - a.txt
      - b.txt
      - c.txt
  lineinfile:
    line: "{{ item.0 }}"
    dest: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ lines | product(files) }}"
```